Help in identifying SMD SMPS driver chip
please help in identifying this chip (use in 12v 5a SMPS board for a driver LED)


Please provide dimensions and a circuit (if you can)

The markings are hard to read. Is first character a 0 or a 9? Is the third character a 6 or a G? Please add this information to the question.

I have the same challenge (unable to make out for sure) even under examination with a good magnifying glass :-(. Tried internet search with both combinations - however, did not find any match

@SundeepGoel Ok. Please add at least the dimensions as requested and take another picture that shows more of the circuit. We need as much information as possible, especially when the markings are unclear.

Ignore this please - i replaced the board.
